# how to use blur event in form using angular..?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jsonschema, angular-schema-form

I make a form using this [link](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/blob/master/docs/index.md#validation-messages)

I able to validate form on button  click, but there is way to validate `onBlur` but I didn't understand how I will achieve this.

Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oaiUn1QWuQVvLFHjnMKy?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >

  <head>    

  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.x" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  </head>

  <body ng-app="test" ng-controller="FormController">

    <form name="ngform"
          sf-schema="schema"
          sf-form="form"
          sf-model="model"  sf-options="{ formDefaults: { ngModelOptions: { updateOn: 'blur' } }}" ng-submit="onSubmit(ngform)"></form>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/icrciconaesuw29/tv4.js?m="></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/unk0id7tmc9w0mm/angular-sanitize.js?m="></script>
  <script src="//dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rk0dfetihiqs7bi/ObjectPath.js"></script>
  <script src="//dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8fq4c4t7jct4w4h/schema-form.js?m="></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//textalk.github.io/angular-schema-form/dist/bootstrap-decorator.min.js"></script>

<script>
angular.module('test',['schemaForm']).controller('FormController', function($scope,$http){
   $scope.schema = {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
      name: { type: "string", minLength: 2, title: "Name", description: "Name or alias" ,required:true},
      "email": {
      "title": "Email",
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^\\S+@\\S+$",
       validationMessage: {
    "default": "Just write a proper address, will you?"   //Special catch all error message
  },
      "description": "Email will be used for evil.",
      required:true
    },
      title: {
        type: "string",
        required:true,
        enum: ['dr','jr','sir','mrs','mr','NaN','dj']
      }
    }
  };

  $scope.form = [
    "*",
    {
      type: "submit",
      title: "Save"
    }
  ];

  $scope.model = {};
   $scope.onSubmit = function(form) {
    // First we broadcast an event so all fields validate themselves
    $scope.$broadcast('schemaFormValidate');

    // Then we check if the form is valid
    if (form.$valid) {
      // ... do whatever you need to do with your data.
    }
  }
})
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: look here http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation. it is a grate angularjs form validation tutorial

Comment: you are giving for static validation I need to dynamically validaton

Comment: You want validate the fields onblur, don't you? read the tutorial, it will help you.

Comment: ok i already read this tutorial..thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ngModelOptions` feature has been [introduced](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/dbe381f29fc72490f8e3a5328d5c487b185fe652) in angularjs v1.3.0-beta.6

You have to use v1.3.0-beta.6 or newer then your plunker will just work!

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/ZCZAcvD2jiBUZhFEcTFA?p=preview

Comment: you include that in your plunker ?

Comment: Yeah, I just changed your plunker to use angularjs to 1.3.0-beta.18

Comment: But still it is not working on blur,..please check on your side

Comment: What exactly do you mean "working on blur"? I see the inputs are validated onblur instead of onchange.

Comment: oh thanks it working now why onchange stop can we do both together ? ...But I have one issue more.can we call fuction on blur..example if I have one field ("Name") I need to check if it contain "sharma" text than it is true else false

Comment: Last please see also one more issue of select field .The issue is whenever I change the value of select field I need to set valur in input field .In my example there is a drop drop "title" .if it value is "dr" I need to set value in "studentname" input field "teststudent" and when it value is"jr" i need to set value "karan" http://plnkr.co/edit/ZNJO3x3IqajjdMNStJMF?p=preview

Comment: due you have any idea